# RSA: plain text to cipher text

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to solve the following question (see below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOeaT.png)

My understanding what in order to go encrypt the plain text (and get the cipher text). I must compute 9^15 mod 2 to get the cipher text? How is the answer 6?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the modulus `n` and the public key `e`.

In your case, the RSA modulus is 15 and the public exponent is 2, and, in general, we write the public key is as a tuple (n,e)=(15,2)

now, RSA (textbook) encryption  calculated as `m^e = mod n`; as a result

9^2 = 6 mod 15

see at [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9%5E2%20mod%2015)

Note: RSA encryption needs padding to be secure against some attacks.

---

as James noted in the comment, this cannot be RSA.

phi(15) = (3-1)*(5-1) = 8.

The inverse of 2 doesn't exist in mod 8. therefore there is no private key. Interestingly, in this case inverse of 3,5,7 mod 8 are also 3,5,8, respectively.

The 2 suggests that this is actually [Rabin Cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem).

Comment: Do you mean the public key is 2?

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!

Comment: Also, it's not really RSA if the exponent is 2, because there is no decrypt exponent. It's the Rabin cryptosystem, and the decryptor instead computes square roots mod p and q.